# SQL Server 2012 Not connecting to Database Engine (Server)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have installed SQL Server 2012 Management Studio, but when I try to connect to server it shows this error

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remove connections. (Provider: SQL Network Interface, error : 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Configuration of connect to server dialog :

- Server type : Database Engine
- Server Name : DESKTOP-DCP12LB\SQLEXPRESS
- Authentication : Windows Authentication

I have tried many solutions but nothing seems to work . During those solutions I found some points that might help diagnose my problem

1. SQL Server Configuration show MMC could not create snap-in error
2. `SQLEXPRESS` service is not starting even when I manually start it
3. SQL Server installation did not ask me for any user-admin option during the installation

Comment: I have installed both the "SQL Server Express with Tools"

Answer (score 0):

If the service will not start, then the root cause of your problems has to do with the current configuration / installation of the service.

Probably easiest to try to uninstall and reinstall of sqlexpress.

If problem persists after a re-install, you should be able to find a more detailed error message down in the event log which will help tell you exactly why the service is unable to start, and you can seek more help with that error message.

Comment: There is not error or warning beign logged I have searched the event logs, Do I have to mark it for storing events from SQLServer ?

Comment: By default sql server will have logging turned on, and output to both windows events, as well as the SQL Server log file ("C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\***\MSSQL\Log\"). Have a look at https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/backup-and-recovery/the-sql-server-instance-that-will-not-start/ for further details on what may prevent sql server from starting.